# postgresql query to mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I want create query in MySQL similiar to PostgreSQL below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION check_unique_pair(IN id1 INTEGER, IN id2 INTEGER) RETURNS INTEGER AS   $body$
DECLARE retval INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
BEGIN 
 SELECT COUNT(*) INTO retval FROM (
  SELECT * FROM edges WHERE a = id1 AND b = id2
  UNION ALL
  SELECT * FROM edges WHERE a = id2 AND b = id1
)  AS pairs;
RETURN retval;
END
$body$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

ALTER TABLE edges ADD CONSTRAINT unique_pair CHECK (check_unique_pair(a, b) < 1);
```

I am new to MySQL.

Comment: try describing your table structure and what you really want to do using this function. Additionally you can check phpmyadmin and MySQL Workbench where you can perform SQL operations graphically.

Comment: This looks like a (buggy and unreliable) attempt to implement an exclusion constraint (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION). Your implementation is extremely unlikely to actually work in the face of any concurrency; it should be urgently replaced with a PostgreSQL 9.1+ exclusion constraint.

Comment: @CraigRinger: that can be achieved with a simple unique index: `create unique index idx_unique_pair on edges (least(a,b), greatest(a,b))`. That also will be a ***lot*** more efficient (but that's not possible in MySQL).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Nice trick. Sometimes the real talent is seeing the simplest possible answer - something you seem to be awfully good at. Also, wow, MySQL doesn't support expression indexes?

Comment: @CraigRinger: correct, MySQL does not support indexes based on expressions. One the many restrictions MySQL has...

Answer (score 3):

The query can be simplified to:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM edges
WHERE a IN (id1, id2)
AND b in (id1, id2)
AND a <> b
   ;
```

, which can probably use a composite index on {a,b}

Comment: That won't provide a constraint, though. For that they'll need a trigger to check that only one row is returned from the (greatly improved) query.

Comment: Embedding it into a trigger function is left as an exercise to the reader. Besides: The question is tagged *both* mysql and postgres, and the trigger syntax may differ. In postgres the whole thing could possibly be implemented by a foreign key constraint + unique{a,b} + CHECK (a<b) and/or a rewrite rule if a happens to be > b.

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought, I just wanted to make sure it was clearly stated.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be attempting to implement an `ASSERTION`, table-level `CHECK` constraint, or an [exclusion constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-EXCLUSION), though the implementation shown won't work reliably.

MySQL doesn't support `CREATE ASSERTION`; neither does any other current RDBMS, as far as I know. Nor is subquery support in `CHECK` for table-level assertions generally supported.

You may need to emulate the behaviour you want using a trigger. See:

- [MySQL assertion-like constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8839540/398670)
- [mysql triggers simulating assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866757)
- [Why don't DBMS's support ASSERTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368349/why-dont-dbmss-support-assertion)
- https://kb.askmonty.org/en/create-assertion-statement/

@a_horse_with_no_name points out in the comments that you can achieve this with a composite unique expression index. MySQL [doesn't support expression indexes](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=4990), so as noted in the comment it won't work in MySQL. Keep an eye on that bug.